# Mostrar Registros De Un Multi Select PHP

Tags: php, html5

Que tal comunidad, tengo el siguiente problema y es el de que quiero mostrar los registros guardados de mi multiselect pero no logro conseguirlo si alguien me ayuda seria de gran ayuda

```html
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-md-4">
<?php
  echo "<select id='dates-field2' class='multiselect-ui form-control' multiple='multiple' name='dias[]' value='".$arreglo['dias']."'>
            <option value='Lunes'>Lunes</option>
            <option value='Martes'>Martes</option>
            <option value='Miercoles'>Miercoles</option>
            <option value='Jueves'>Jueves</option>
            <option value='Viernes'>Viernes</option>
            <option value='Sabado'>Sabado</option>
            <option value='Domingo'>Domingo</option>
        </select>";
    ?>
    
        <br><br>
    </div>
</div>


<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $('.multiselect-ui').multiselect({
        includeSelectAllOption: true
    });
});
</script>
```

[image: Es Asi Como Lo Tengo]

Comment: Buenos dias, puedes ser mas especifico, pero trataré de interpretar lo que preguntas y me dices si tengo la razon o no, "Creo que se refiere a que si se selecciona un option con el valodr (Lunes) muestre los datos que esten ligados a ese dia, con el valor del option (martes) .... y asi sucesivamente", estare pendiente!

Comment: Discupame lo que deseo es que en ese select se muestren los registros guardados en mi BD Si Necesitas Algo Dime

Comment: Bueno, primero, ¿que lenguaje esperas usar del lado del Cliente? para mi el hecho de usar JS es mucho mas viable que usar solo PHP, " con el fin de dar respuestas rápidas a las acciones del usuario sin necesidad de enviar la información de lo que ha hecho el usuario al servidor y esperar respuesta de éste (lo que haría más lento los procesos)."

Comment: Envíalo por post o por ajax, ahora mismo no hay una orden de que nadie lo reciba..  :/

Answer (score 1):

Por el ejemplo, debe colocar cada uno de los valores del arreglo en los options. Also así

```php
$options = "";
foreach($dia as $arreglo['dias']) {
  $options .= "<option value='" . $dia . "'>" . $dia . "</option>";
}
echo $options; // Imprime los options, no el select completo.
```

Comment: Lo tengo asi, estoy bien asi o como debe ser <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-md-4">
    <select id="dates-field2" class="multiselect-ui form-control" multiple="multiple" name="dias[]">
            <?php 
            $options = "";
foreach($dia as $arreglo['dias']) {
  $options .= "<option value='" . $dia . "'>" . $dia . "</option>";
}
echo $options; // Imprime los options, no el select completo.
            }?> 
            </select>

    
        <br><br>
    </div>
</div>

Comment: Debería mostrar como desea, no ?

Answer (score 1):

Usar:

```
//Dias a marcar
var diasGuardados=['Lunes','Miercoles']
//multiselect con dias marcados
$('.multiselect-ui').multiselect('select', diasGuardados);
```

Podrías usar un ajax para obtener el array `diasGuardados` desde la BD.